# AngularJS 2: Changing the value of a variable outside of the class that the variable belongs to

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very simple question which I don't really know how to Google...  I've 2 components here, the first one is playlist.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Video} from './video';
import {VideoFrame} from './videoiFrame.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'playlist',
   templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
   inputs: ['videos']
})

export class PlaylistComponent {
   /*
    OnClick
   */
   onSelect(vid:Video) {
   /* change the value of this.videoID in videoiFrame here*/
   }
}
```

the other one is videoiFrame.component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Video} from './video';

@Component({
  selector: 'ytVideo',
  templateUrl: 'app/ts/videoiFrame.component.html',
})

export class VideoFrame {
  videoID:string;

  constructor() {
    this.videoID = "123456";
  }
}
```

How can I change the videoID variable via the onSelect?

I tried doing: `new VideoFrame().videoID = "newID";` I'd expect that it would work like that but it doesn't.
 `

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Angular 2 documentation is one of best documentation i ever see. If you are a beginner and started with documentation step by step it would be all clear and simple, obviously u skipped crucial things.

Comment: Sorry, I am just frustrated with this because I really want to learn it but it's so much to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to communicate via parent component:

PlaylistComponent:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'playlist',
   templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
   inputs: ['videos']
})

export class PlaylistComponent {
   @Output('onVideoSelect')
   public onVideoSelect: EventEmitter<Video> = new EventEmitter();
   onSelect(vid:Video) {
      this.onVideoSelect.emit(vid);
   }
}
```

VideoComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ytVideo',
  templateUrl: 'app/ts/videoiFrame.component.html',
})

export class VideoFrame {
  @Input('video')
  public video: Video = null;
}
```

ParentComponent (whatever it is):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent'
})

export class ParentComponent {
  public selectedVideo: Video = null;

  public selectVideo(video: Video) {
     this.selectedVideo = video;
  }
}
```

In parent component template:

```
<playlist (onVideoSelect)="selectVideo($event)"></playlist>
<yt-video [video]="selectedVideo></yt-video>
```

Other options would be to use a Service with is having a `selectedVideo$` Observable or you could use Redux.

Comment: How do you know they have a parent-child relationship?

Comment: I don't know i'm assuming it. Thats why i added other possible options in communication between components. But for more he should read the docs :)